# Brown-Henneaux central charge in Chern-Simons formulation

Tags: general-relativity, boundary-conditions

In the article of [Pérez, Tempo and Troncoso](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04490), in the Chern-Simons formulation for three-dimensional general relativity, they compute the canonical generator of charges
\begin{align}
Q\left[\varepsilon\right]=-\frac{k}{8\pi}\int d\phi\; \varepsilon\,\mathcal{L},
\end{align}
where $\varepsilon=f(t+\phi)$ and $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}(t,\phi)$ is a dynamic field. They state that, knowing the transformation
\begin{align}
\delta\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{D}\varepsilon,
\end{align}
with $\mathcal{D}=\partial_\phi \mathcal{L}+2\mathcal{L}\partial_\phi-2\partial_\phi^3$, and recalling that $\left\{Q[\varepsilon_1],Q[\varepsilon_2]\right\}=\delta_{\varepsilon_2}Q[\varepsilon_1]$, it is possible to obtain two independent copies of the Virasoro algebra with the Brown–Henneaux central extension.

The attempt was to compute the definition, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\left\{Q[\varepsilon_1],Q[\varepsilon_2]\right\}=\delta_{\varepsilon_2}Q[\varepsilon_1]=-\frac{k}{8\pi}\int d\phi\; \varepsilon_1\delta_{\varepsilon_2}\mathcal{L}&=-\frac{k}{8\pi}\int d\phi\; \varepsilon_1\mathcal{D}\varepsilon_2\\
&=-\frac{k}{8\pi}\int d\phi\;\varepsilon_1 \left(\varepsilon_2\mathcal{L}'+3\mathcal{L}\varepsilon_2'-2\varepsilon_2'''\right),
\end{align}
however, I do not know how to proceed. I understand that I have to consider at some moment a Fourier expansion (because we have the same operator acting in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/543019/289490)), but I do not know at which point.

Comment: Take the $\epsilon$ to be a Fourier mode. Invert to solve for $\mathcal{L}$ in terms of the $Q_n$, plug this into your result for the bracket. If you've not made any errors, you will have the Virasoro algebra.

Comment: Sorry the dummy question, but I do not understand how to fulfill the first part. Do you mean: a) Expand $\varepsilon$ in Fourier modes on the charge, that is, $Q[\varepsilon]=-\frac{k}{8\pi}\int d\phi\;\sum_{n}\varepsilon_n e^{in\phi}\;\mathcal{L}$, but how could I invert this expression? and b) I think it would be straightforward, because I will have to compute $\left\{Q_n,Q_m\right\}=\int d\phi\; \left\{Q[\varepsilon_1],Q[\varepsilon_2]\right\}e^{-in\phi-im\phi'}$.

Comment: Literally $\epsilon = e^{in\phi}$. You may need to play around with whether you put a positive in the exponent or an overall minus in front of $\epsilon$. I don't remember off the top of my head which set of conventions should give the standard form of the algebra.